# Convert Unicode smiley to nsstring ios

Tags: ios

I'm working on chat app.I want add support of smiley. I can show smiley direct in iOS using unicode like `\ue415` for :-). When I send message using this unicode string than other side is receiving square box like ``. How to convert unicode character to nsstring.

I'm using emotion in collection view like bellow

**Code :**

```
data = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"\ue415",@"\ue056",@"\ue057",@"\ue414",@"\ue405",@"\ue106",@"\ue418",@"\ue417",@"\ue40d",@"\ue40a",@"\ue404",@"\ue105",@"\ue409",@"\ue40e",@"\ue402",@"\ue108",@"\ue403",@"\ue058",@"\ue407",@"\ue401",@"\ue40f",@"\ue40b",@"\ue406",@"\ue413",@"\ue411",@"\ue412",@"\ue410",@"\ue107",@"\ue059",@"\ue416",@"\ue408",@"\ue40c",@"\ue11a",@"\ue10c",@"\ue32c",@"\ue32a",@"\ue32d",@"\ue328",@"\ue32b",@"\ue022",@"\ue023",nil];
```

**CollectionView Delegate Methods**

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"EmojiCell";

    UICollectionViewCell *cell =[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    UILabel *lable = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];

    lable.text = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    messageField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",messageField.text,[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}
```

**Code For Sending A Message**

```
NSString *messageStr = self.messageField.text ;

    if([messageStr length] > 0) {

        NSXMLElement *body = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"body"];
        [body setStringValue: messageStr];

        XMPPJID *jid = [XMPPJID jidWithString:chatWithUser];

        NSXMLElement *message = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"message"];
        [message addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"chat"];
        [message addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:[jid full]];
        [message addChild:body];

        [self.xmppStream sendElement:message];
    }
```

Comment: And the "other side" is your app too?

Comment: Other side I'm using the mac messages app.

Comment: OK, so how are you formatting the message you send (seeing code would be useful here).

Answer (score 0):

Just change symbolCode.

```
unichar symbolCode = 0xf086;
NSString *chatIcon =[NSString stringWithCharacters:&symbolCode length:1];
```

Edited for you:

```
unichar symbolCode = 0xE415;
NSString *smile =[NSString stringWithCharacters:&symbolCode length:1];
NSLog(@"%@",smile);
UILabel *lab = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 20, 100, 50)];
lab.text = smile;
[self.view addSubview:lab];
```

[image]

Comment: I print the chatIcon value in log. It's showing square box

Comment: Thanks for answer but displaying the smile in iOS is not my problem I can show  smiley in iOS directly like `lab.text = @"\ue415"`